# Verifying my proof of $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This is an even problem in a textbook I'm reviewing. I've struggled with proofs involving sets in the past, one big reason I'm reviewing this textbook, and want to know if I'm onto the right track with this. Education level is at the beginning proof writing level.

> Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets. Prove if $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$, then $B=C$
>
> Assume $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$. Let $x \in B$. Since $A \cup B = A \cup C$, it follows that $x \in A$ or $x \in C$. If $x \in C$, then we have demonstrated that $B \subseteq C$, so let $x \in A$. Thus $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, implying $x \in A \cap B$. Since $A \cap B = A \cap C$, $x \in A \cap C$ which is equivalent to saying $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. Thus $x \in C$, therefore $B \subseteq C$.
>
> The proof of $C \subseteq B$ is extremely similar to the proof of $B \subseteq C$ and thus isn't included. Therefore $B=C$.

Comment: Aside from saying "we have demonstrated that $B\subseteq C$" prematurely when you've only covered the first of two cases, your proof is correct.

Comment: Ooh.... no.  When you choose an  $x \in B$ and said if $x \in C$ then that is only true for this *specific* $x$.  It is not true of *any* $x \in B$ so you have *not* shown $B \subset C$.  Say $B = \{0,2\}; A=\{0\}; C=\{2\}$.  Choose $2 \in B$.  $2 \in C$.  THat does *NOT* mean $B \subset C$.

Comment: Thanks Danny. Also Flea how else should I have done it? It seems like the first assumption we made prevents that specific scenario from occurring.

Comment: The first assumption comes later.  You can never claim: "Let x be arbitrary.  Either x is One thing or the Other.  If x is One thing we have demonstrated all x is One thing because x was arbitrary."  x *stops* being arbitrary as soon as you make any assumption about the x you picked.  Simply say:  "If $x \in B$ then $x \in C$ or $x \in A$.  If $x \in A$ then $x \in C$.  So either way $x \in C$." that way because you've covered *BOTH* cases and got the same result *now* is is okay to say $B \subset C$.  You can't say it for only one of the cases.

Comment: Ah I think I get what you guys mean. That makes a lot more sense. It's only a subset if I can show x is an element of C in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have mentioned, the only problem is your statement "then we have demonstrated $B\subseteq C$". You can get around this fairly easily. From the start, when you say "Let $x\in B$", follow it up with "and we shall show $x\in C$". Then you can replace the problematic part with "If $x\in C$ then we are done, so assume $x\in A$".

Additionally, rather than say "The proof of $C\subseteq B$ is extremely similar..." you could, at the top, write "Observe by symmetry that is sufficient to prove $B\subseteq C$" or "By interchanging the role of $B$ and $C$, note that we need only prove $B\subseteq C$". It's a small thing but I find it a little neater.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A\cap B = A\cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$.

Let $x \in B$. [For style and clarity add: so $x \in A \cup B$ so $x \in A\cup C$.]

It follows that $x \in A$ or $x \in C$.  [Okay, but I prefer a little clarity]

If $x \in C$ we have demonstrated that $B \subset C$.  [NO!!!! huge buzzer, no.  We have demonstrated that *THAT* $x \in C$ but not that *all $x \in C$.  Instead say: "If $x \in C$ then $x \in C$".  ... Yes, I know that seems redundant but bear with me.  You can NOT say $B \subset of C$ yet.  Only $x \in C$.]

[Otherwise] if $x \in A$. Thus $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ implying ..... is equivalent to saying $x \in A$ and $x \in C$.  Thus $x \in C.  [That is all good.  But now the *CORRECT* way to state your conclusion.]

[Add: So either way, if $x \in B$ then either $x \in C$ or  $x \in A$ and therefore $x \in C$.]

So $x \in C$ Thus $B \subset C$.

The proof of $C \subset B$ is extremely similar and is not included. [Mmmmmmm.... okay.  But I really don't like that.  I'd prefer something like "An identical argument can be made by selecting $x \in C$ and showing $x$ must also be in $B$."  But I'd give you credit for what you say.]

My biggest complaint is "$x \in C \implies B \subset C$" prematurely.  That is premature and not the actual implication.